# contour plot bivariate lognormal density function python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to contour plot a bivariate lognormal PDF of the random variables R~LN(7, 0.5) and S~LN(1, 0.5) using this python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import lognorm

r= np.linspace(1, 10, 500)
s= np.linspace(1, 10, 500)
R, S = np.meshgrid(r, s)

sigma_R = 0.5
mu_R = 7

sigma_S = 0.5
mu_S = 1

#lognormal PDF
pdf_R = lognorm.pdf(R.flatten(), 1, mu_R, sigma_R)
pdf_S = lognorm.pdf(S.flatten(), 1, mu_S, sigma_S)
JointPDF = pdf_R*pdf_S

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CS2 = ax.contour(R, S, JointPDF.reshape(500,500), 30, cmap="RdBu_r")
```

The result is:

[image]

Q1: is this plot correct? i am not sure because the contour plots are not supposed to start from 1 and 7 which correponds to the mean values of the RVs.

Q2: does anyone know how to do in case R and S are correlated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with Q1. No the plot is likely not what you want, mostly due to somewhat confusing interface for lognorm in scipy,
and your notation LN(7,0.5) not being clear. So if you can clarify that it would be helpful. But to progress, I assume that  you want lognormal distribution with mean and sigma as defined in say [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) with Wikipedia's parameters mu, sigma being mu_R=**log**(7) and sigma_R = 0.5 (otherwise the scale of the numbers do not make sense)

so if mu, sigma are the two parameters as defined in [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), then you want to call `lognorm` as follows

```
pdf_R = lognorm.pdf(R.flatten(), sigma_R, 0, mu_R)
```

(and similar for pdf_S)

you also want to be a bit careful with your domain. The distribution will be centered around (7,1), defined on (0,inf) x (0, inf) and width of the order of a few multiples of your sigmas. if you want it symmetric I would make the domain [0,10]x[0,10]:

```
r= np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
s= np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
```

Q2 is a different matter altogether so I will leave it at that

[image: correct lognormal countour plot]

Comment: thanks for your answer.  R is a lognormal RV with parameters mu_R=7 and sigma_R=0.5, so i should use scipy this way: pdf_R = lognorm.pdf(R.flatten(), sigma_R, 0, exp(mu_R))

Comment: this seemed like a possible interpretation of LN(7,0.5) to me with the only hesitation being the fact that exp(7) is a fairly large number -- quite a bit larger than exp(mu_S) = exp(1) (about x400 larger) so your contour graph would really look quite weird

Comment: another possible interpretation is that the expected value of your LN variable is 7 and standard deviation is 0.5 (so variance is 0.5^2=0.25) This would translate into yet another set of mu, sigma (using the formulas from the wikipedia article I linked).

Comment: The second interpretation is more likely. Using wikipedia formulas for mu and sigma with the lognormal of scipy gives the desired result , note that: pdf_R = lognormal.pdf(R.flatten(), sigma, 0, exp(mu))

Answer (score 0):

as an answer to Q2 of my question i found the following expression in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogMultinormalDistribution.html

[image]

which is an explicit formula of the bivariate lognoraml PDF. Here is a beginner code but it could help

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

""" lognormal parameters """
def mu_z(mu, sigma):
    mu_Z = np.log(mu/(np.sqrt(1+(sigma/mu)**2)))
    return mu_Z
def sigma_z(mu, sigma):
    sigma_Z = np.sqrt(np.log(1+(sigma/mu)**2))
    return sigma_Z

r= np.linspace(1, 10, 500)
s= np.linspace(1, 10, 500)
R, S = np.meshgrid(r, s)

sigma_R = 0.5
mu_R = 7
Z_R = np.log(R)
sigma_ZR = sigma_z(mu_R, sigma_R)
mu_ZR = mu_z(mu_R, sigma_R)

sigma_S = 0.5
mu_S = 1
Z_S = np.log(S)
sigma_ZS = sigma_z(mu_S, sigma_S)
mu_ZS = mu_z(mu_S, sigma_S)

rho = 0.5
A = 1/(2 * R.flatten()* S.flatten()*np.pi*np.sqrt(sigma_ZR**2*sigma_ZS**2-rho**2*sigma_ZR**2*sigma_ZS**2))
C = (np.log(R.flatten())-mu_ZR)*(-((rho*(np.log(S.flatten())-mu_ZS)*sigma_ZR*sigma_ZS)/
    (sigma_ZR**2*sigma_ZS**2-rho**2*sigma_ZR**2*sigma_ZS**2))+
    (((np.log(R.flatten())-mu_ZR)*sigma_ZS**2)/
    (sigma_ZR**2*sigma_ZS**2-rho**2*sigma_ZR**2*sigma_ZS**2)))
B = (np.log(S.flatten())-mu_ZS)*((((np.log(S.flatten())-mu_ZS)*sigma_ZR**2)/
    (sigma_ZR**2*sigma_ZS**2-rho**2*sigma_ZR**2*sigma_ZS**2))-
    ((rho*(np.log(R.flatten())-mu_ZR)*sigma_ZS*sigma_ZR)/
    (sigma_ZR**2*sigma_ZS**2-rho**2*sigma_ZR**2*sigma_ZS**2)))
    
pdflnmv = A*np.exp(-(C+B)/2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CS4 = ax.contour(R, S, pdflnmv.reshape(500,500))
```

when rho = 0.5 (rho is the correlation coefficient) the result is

[image]

when rho = 0.0 (uncorrelated RVs) we have the answer for my Q1

[image]